# Flask admin input field to choose file field

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm using cloudinary to store my images. My image column in database is `String` so default flask-admin input field for image is text field.

How do I change the image text input field to upload image input field in flask-admin page?

I want to get that image file and convert to String cloudinary url to store, not directly paste some url in text input field.

[flask admin text form field]

[image: 1]